# How to draw an arc with different start and end thickness in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to drawn an arc with different start and end thickness as shown in the below image in flutter. 
[image]

Comment: You can use two circles with different radius and different end points

Comment: @meditat: How to draw two circle with different radius and different end points?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using two half-circle, I have made a demo please check below code is it works for you

[image]

Half Circle Class

```
class CustomHalfCircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Build Method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipPath(
              clipper: new CustomHalfCircleClipper(),
              child: new Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2)),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 1,
              left: 40,
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: new CustomHalfCircleClipper(),
                child: new Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20) / 2)),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: @KailashChouhan: I need logic for calculating this kind of path. Not only for half circle, but also arc varies based on different start and end angle. Moreover, I do not use widget for displaying path. I need to draw path in a canvas using the custom painter

Answer (score 1):

The logic is to use two circles one over the other. The circle on top is displaced towards right. You can achieve this by a CustomPainter.

```
Paint backCirclePaint = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
  ..color = Colors.blue;

Paint frontCirclePaint = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
  ..color = Colors.white;

canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width/2, size.height/2), radius: 100.0), 
  0.0, -(2 * pi * percentage) / 100, true, backCirclePaint);

// percentage is responsible for the amount(angle) of arc you want to build.

canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width/2 + 10.0, size.height/2), radius: 90.0), 
  0.0, -(2 * pi * percentage) / 100, true, frontCirclePaint);
```